# how can jump from python to c++ in mxnet

Tags: mxnet

Now i am reading source code in mxnet. The code about reading data is that 
  train_dataiter = mx.io.MNISTIter().And I found the class MNISTIter: public IIterator {}is implenmented in src/io. How can it jump from python to c++?I have wondered how wrapped.Who can help to explained?

Answer (score 1):

The data iters implemented in cpp are registered as python functions at runtime. Here're some related functions to do that: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/io.py#L778